# mapping similar strings to same number values

Tags: machine-learning

I need a way to map strings to a numeric space, where the mapping moves similar strings to the same number.

For example:

in

```
str1 = 'some random string one'
str2 = 'some rzndom string one'
str3 = 'some rndom string one'
str4 = 'a very different string'
```

we would want [`str1`, `str2`, `str3`] all to be mapped to the same number, while `str4` be mapped to a relatively distant number

We can assume all the strings are lowercase and have no punctuation.

### What I've tried

So far, I've come up with using the sum of the ascii values and rounding down by some factor:

```py
class StringMapper(TestCase):
    def translate_string_to_numeric_space(self, strr: str, granularity: int) -> int:
        list_of_char_vals = [ord(c) for c in strr]
        sum_of_chars = sum(list_of_char_vals)
        granularity_reduced_sum = self.round_down_to_nearest_multiple_of(sum_of_chars, granularity)
        return granularity_reduced_sum

    @staticmethod
    def round_down_to_nearest_multiple_of(num: int, multiple: int) -> int:
        return num - (num % multiple)
```

Then we get:

```py
vals = [self.translate_string_to_numeric_space(s, 100) for s in [str1, str2, str3, str4]]
```

> [2100, 2100, 2000, 2200]

##### What works in this solution:

1. it allowed a single typo ('a' -> 'z' in `str1`, `str2`)

##### What didn't work in this solution:

1. it did not allow for omissions (`str3` was not grouped with `str1` and `str2`)
2. it did not create sufficient distance between `str4` and the others

Welcoming any ideas, thank you!!

---

Clarification
String-to-string comparison such as jaro-winkler or levenstein is not an option, as we have a very large number of strings, and pair-wise comparison squares the number of operations

Comment: It looks that you need [Locality-sensitive hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be useful to frame this problem using common terminology. Hashing is mapping an object, a string in this case, to an integer. What you want are collisions (i.e., similar objects are mapped to the same integer bucket). The goal is to pick a hashing function that does that based on the number of shared letters in the string.

A scalable implementation of this idea is MinHash and locality-sensitive hashing (LSH).

Here is a rough version using Python's datasketch library:

```py
from datasketch import MinHash, MinHashLSH

str1 = 'some random string one'
str2 = 'some rzndom string one'
str3 = 'some rndom string one'
str4 = 'a very different string'
strings = [str1, str2, str3, str4]

# Hash each string, letter-by-letter
hashes = []
for s in strings:
    m = MinHash(num_perm=128)
    for c in s:
        m.update(c.encode('utf8')) 
    hashes.append(m)

# Create LSH storage
lsh = MinHashLSH(threshold=0.8, num_perm=128)
for n, hash_value in enumerate(hashes, 1):
    lsh.insert(f"str{n}", hash_value)

# Test that the queries for the hash values return expected neighbors
hash_str1 = hashes[0]
assert set(lsh.query(hash_str1)) == set(['str1', 'str2', 'str3'])
hash_str4 = hashes[3]
assert set(lsh.query(hash_str4)) == set(['str4'])
```

Comment: can you please update your code to produce the numeric value? (as opposed to putting all the MinHashes in a dict

Comment: The MinHashes are in a list. You can index the list to get the numeric value - hashes[0].hashvalues

Comment: Apologies for not awarding the bounty in time - I wasn't aware that it would expire, and now that I came here again it's too late

Answer (score 1):

It seems that a **string similarity metric** might help.

The **Levenshtein distance** could be useful and it has a python module:

```py
from Levenshtein import distance

str1 = 'some random string one'
str2 = 'some rzndom string one'
str3 = 'some rndom string one'
str4 = 'a very different string'

print(distance(str1, str2))
print(distance(str1, str3))
print(distance(str1, str4))
```

Output:

```py
1
1
18
```

You might need further investigation as it only gives you relative distances, not an absolute mapping. Maybe using [Nearest Neighbors](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#nearest-neighbors) with the Levenshtein distance will work.

Hope it helps

Comment: thank you, added a clarification as to why we can't do distance metrics

Comment: Thank you. Could you detail what you want to achieve in this numerical space ? I am curious to understand the limitations of using the distance metrics

Comment: we have hundreds of millions of strings, if we do pair wise we'll have that many operations squared, which would be infeasible. I'm looking for a clever mathematical solution rather than build a massively parallelized string distance calculator system

Comment: How representative is your example? In particular, do any two "similar" strings differ by only a few typos?

Comment: *if we do pair wise*: You don't need to do pair wise, you could use BallTree-like approaches in the search of nearest neighbors. *we have hundreds of millions of strings*: could you give us more context about the data you have and what you want to achieve in this numerical space ?

Answer (score 0):

For most cases, the following code will work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> s;
    s.push_back("some random string one");
    s.push_back("some rzndom string one");
    s.push_back("some rndom string one");
    s.push_back("a very different string");
    s.push_back("it doesn'n work");
    s.push_back("it works");
    s.push_back("money back");
    s.push_back("back money");
    for (auto c : s) {
        vector<double> v;
        v.resize(c.size());
        double d = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<c.size()-1; i++) {
          v[i] = c[i]-c[i+1];
        }
        v[v.size()-1] = c[c.size()-1]-c[0];
        for (int i=0; i<v.size(); i++) {
          d += exp(-(v[i]*v[i]));
        }
        d *= pow(1.0/v.size(),1.0/v.size());
        cout << d << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Results for this example will be:
0.687062
0.687062
0.683994
1.53064
0.0153933
9.5162e-05
0.62808
0.613531